# Present data from python dictionary to django template.?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a dictionary

```
data = {'sok': [ [1, 10] ], 'sao': [ [1, 10] ],'sok&sao':[ [2,20]] }
```

How Can I (Loop trough Dictionary ) present My data as (HTML) table to Django template.??
This format that as table

```
 author       qty            Amount
 sok            1              10         
 sao            1              10         
 sok&sao        2              20
 total
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the `dict.items()` method to get the dictionary elements:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>author</td>
        <td>qty</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
    </tr>

    {% for author, values in data.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{author}}</td>
        {% for v in values.0 %}
        <td>{{v}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Edited into answer for posterity.

Comment: On python 2.x, you should use `data.iteritems` rather than `data.items`.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, django templates do not deal with Python tuples.  So it is not legal to use "for author, values" in the template.  Instead, you must access tuple or array values by their index by using ".index", as in "tuple.0" and "tuple.1".

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>author</td>
        <td>qty</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
    </tr>

    {% for entry in data.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{entry.0}}</td>
        {% for v in entry.1 %}
        <td>{{v}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

In a project im working on now, i have had the same problem, thanks to your replies i've ended up doing something like this and it worked fine:

```
<table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
<tr>
    <td>author</td>
    <td>qty</td>
    <td>Amount</td>
</tr>
{% for k,v in resultado.iteritems %}
    <tr><td> {{ k }} </td><td>{{ v[0] }}</td><td> {{ v[1] }} </td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```